# How to escape shell script to run it using command_string option?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am trying to escape the following script to run it via shell command-string option ( /bin/sh -c ).

```
privateIP=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet " | awk \'{print $2}\');
sed -i  "s/http:\/\/:/http:\/\/$privateIP:/g" init.conf
```

Please elaborate on the answer.

Comment: you need to show how you are using `/bin/sh -c`. What do you intend to do with `$privateIP` once you have assigned it? Are  you sure that value returned is as you need/expect? and WilliamPursell is showing you the correct syntax for doing substitutions when you have `/` chars in you str or replacment, i.e. `'s@http....@.....@g'`. . If you're getting a sed error, then you should show the exact command that is being executed. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're question is not clear, but perhaps you are looking for:

```
sh -c 'privateIP=$(ifconfig eth0 | awk "/inet/{print \$2}"); 
  sed -i "s@http://:@http://$privateIP:@g" init.conf'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your command and I get - sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated `s' command error. FYI I am trying to run a shell script .sh file inline with /bin/sh -c option and stuck with escaping the script